# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExcetion when trying to clone an array

Tags: java, arrays, clone, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to clone the first array.
It sometimes throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExpection`? Why did that happen and how can I fix it?.

```
  import java.util.Random;
    
    public class CloneArray {
    
    
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            
             Random rand = new Random();
             
             int[] arr = new Random().ints(16, 1, 16 + 1).sorted().toArray();
             int[] clone = arr;   
            
             for (int element: arr) {
                System.out.println(arr[element]);
             }
             
         System.out.println("---Clone the Array----");
             
             //clone the array 
             for (int ele: clone) {
                System.out.println(clone[ele]);
             }
        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following enhanced `for` loop, you are trying to access an element like you do by using index:

```
for (int element: arr) {
    System.out.println(arr[element]);
}
```

The array, `arr` can have the last element as `16` and thus for this value,  `arr[element]` will be translated to `arr[16]` causing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is because the size of `arr[]` is `16` and therefore the last index in `arr[]` is `15`. Similar is the case when you are trying to access elements of `clone[]`.

Replace

```
System.out.println(arr[element]);
System.out.println(clone[ele]);
```

with

```
System.out.println(element);
System.out.println(ele);
```

The corrected code will be as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int[] arr = new Random().ints(16, 1, 16 + 1).sorted().toArray();
        int[] clone = arr;

        for (int element : arr) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
        System.out.println("---Clone the Array----");
        for (int ele : clone) {
            System.out.println(ele);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use index-style to access the elements from the array:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int[] arr = new Random().ints(16, 1, 16 + 1).sorted().toArray();
        int[] clone = arr;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("---Clone the Array----");
        for (int i = 0; i < clone.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(clone[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** You should use `int[] clone = arr.clone()` to clone `arr[]`. When you do `int[] clone = arr`, the array reference `clone[]` will keep referencing the same elements i.e. any change on an index of `arr[]` will be reflected in the same way when accessing the value on that index using `clone[]` e.g.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new Random().ints(16, 1, 16 + 1).sorted().toArray();
        int[] clone = arr;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(clone));

        arr[4] = 100;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(clone));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 13, 14, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 13, 14, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 13, 14, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 13, 14, 16]
```

On the other hand,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new Random().ints(16, 1, 16 + 1).sorted().toArray();
        int[] clone = arr.clone();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(clone));

        arr[4] = 100;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(clone));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 100, 3, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15]
```

Comment: After replace with System.out.println(ele);
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExpection would still happen, and my numbers in ele is not the same as in element.

Answer (score 3):

To actually clone the array, you should use the `.clone()` method. (Note that this will only work for one dimensional arrays.) With a [for each loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html), you should simply print `ele` instead of trying to use the elements of the array as indexes.

```
int[] arr = new Random().ints(16, 1, 16 + 1).sorted().toArray();
int[] clone = arr.clone();  
//...
for (int ele: clone) {
   System.out.println(ele);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the for loop `element` is the item of the array and not its index. Using items value as index will sometimes exceed the array size. The outcome is based on the random values you use to fill the array and therefor it is reproducible only randomly.